# How to make combination of 'and and 'or' operator to get the data in mongo db in java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following input json data to get the filtered result from the database:

```
  {
       "title": "course",
       "filter": {
        "subject": ["java"],
        "branch": ["CS", "IT"]
    }
```

From the above input json data, I need to filter out the records in the following scenario:

The result contains search string "course" AND  subject is "java" AND branch is "CS" OR "IT".

The following code is used:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SearchRequest{

    private String title;
    
    private Map<String, Object> filters;
}

I have tried to following code for the desired output:
 
 public List<CourseEntity> getData(SearchRequest searchParams) {
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("title").is(searchParams.getTitle()).andOperator(Criteria.where("subject").is(searchParams.getFilters().get("subject"))
        .andOperator(Criteria.where("branch").in(searchParams.getFilters().get("branch")))));
}
```

But did not succeed by this way. How can we get this?

Comment: What is contained in `searchParams.getFilters().get("branch")`? Is it a `List`?

Comment: Also in your input JSON, I see `subject` is represented as `Array`. If there will always be single subject, then it should be `String`.

Comment: yes   searchParams.getFilters().get("branch")- its a list. private Map<String, List<String>> filters;

subject can have multiple value and of array type.

Answer (score 1):

If the branch is a list, first you can collect them into a new list of Criteria:

```
ArrayList<Criteria> branchCriteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String branch : searchParams.getFilter().getBranch()) {
        branchCriteriaList.add(Criteria.where("branch").is(branch));
    }
```

Then using this list, you can build your AND operators, and inside that you can add the branch criteria list as an OR operator as the following:

```
query.addCriteria(
            new Criteria().andOperator(
                    Criteria.where("title").is(searchParams.getTitle()),
                    Criteria.where("subject").is(searchParams.getFilter().getSubject()),
                    new Criteria().orOperator(branchCriteriaList.toArray(Criteria[]::new))
            )
    );
```